# Adding Javascript to the Administrator Template

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, administrator, template-override

Is there a way to add Javascript to the Joomla Administrator template without creating a child template?

Something equivalent to `/media/templates/administrator/atum/css/user.css` for Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a system plugin that only works in the back-end and loads some JavaScript file.

Probably with something like:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgSystemPluginname extends CMSPlugin
{

  protected $app;

  public function onAfterRender()
  {
    // Quit this when the app is not in the administrator back-end
    if (!$this->app->isClient('administrator'))
    {
      return;
    }

    // Load some JavaScript file
    HTMLHelper::_('script','com_foo/foo.js', 
    ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);
  }
}
```